# How to update Dell repositories after upgrading XPS 13 to Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: upgrade, dell, repository

I have just updated my Dell XPS 13 (9360) to Ubuntu 18.04.  It came pre-installed with Ubuntu 16.04.

The upgrade has worked fine.  However, during the upgrade process the installer disabled the dell repositories.  The repositories all seem to reference Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial:

```
# deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell public # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell public # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell-dino2-mlk public # disabled on upgrade to bionic
### deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell-dino2-mlk public
# deb http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell-service public # disabled on upgrade to bionic
# deb-src http://dell.archive.canonical.com/updates/ xenial-dell-service public
```

My questions are:

- should I replace references to 'xenial' with 'bionic' and re-enable the repositories?
- Do the repositories have any important packages?
- Would it matter if I don't re-enable them?

Comment: 1.  You could try. Bionic-dell and bionic-dell-service are there, and the third one isn't. 2. Who knows, ...might want to search, or ask Dell. 3. Only you can tell if it matters or not.

Comment: I've looked at the repositories.  bionic-dell and bionic-dell-service appear to be empty. bionic-dell-dino2-mlk doesn't exist.  I presume that this means that they aren't needed but I will see if I can get an answer from Dell.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've spoken to Dell about this and am posting this answer here in case it helps anyone else.

**Updated 11 Oct 2018**

Dell have said that they do now support Ubuntu 18.04 on the XPS 13 9360 (previously they had said that they didn't). The disabled repositories are not necessary and are not supported in Ubuntu 18.04 ('bionic').

In answer to my question, no, you shouldn't replace 'xenial' with 'bionic' and re-enable the repositories.

The "dino2-mlk" is apparently the codename for the 9360 model of the XPS 13.  As mentioned in the comments there isn't a `bionic-dell-dino2-mlk` repository.

The repositories contain drivers and other updates.

Comment: Thanks! Good to know this, since I took the freedom of upgrading without knowing this. I was scared because version upgrades where disabled by default in my device. Did they make a public statement or you got this in a private communication?

Comment: I got this via a conversation with the support team. Glad it helped!

Comment: I don't really understand the logic behind your answer. If Dell does support 18.04 on the 9360, then that implies that we need to enable a repo from which to obtain driver updates. Either the original xenial repos or some new bionic repos.

Comment: @oulenz Dell said that the disabled repositories weren't necessary. I presume this means that the driver updates are provided via the main Ubuntu repositories.

Comment: How did you contact Dell? I have a similar issue now, with the Dell XPS 13 7390, which I'm trying to upgrade to Ubuntu 22.04.

Comment: @becko I can't remember exactly. I think I opened a support request.